# Inverted Index in Python + Posting Lists for Query - I need help getting my code to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I have been working on a code for creating an inverted Index in Python. I am a total beginner and my Code is not working yet.
The instructions for this assignment were clear: read multiple files at once, tokenize the text and remove duplicates. Stopwords do not have to be removed (for now), and stemming is also not required. Hashmaps are not allowed.
This is my code for the first part of this assignment:

```
import os
from collections import Counter


path= r'C:\Users\Name\Documents' 
files = dict()
for filename in os.listdir(path):           
    files_to_read = path + "\\" + filename    
    corpus = open(files_to_read, "r", encoding="utf-8")
    text=corpus.read()    
    files[filename]=text


def lower(text):   
    text=text.lower()
    return text


def tokenize(str):
    tokens = dict()
    words = str.split()
    tokens= Counter(words)
    return tokens

def individualwords(dictionary):
    individual=list()
    for word in dictionary:
        if word not in individual:
            individual.append(word)
    return individual


def inverted_index():
    idx = {}
    for file in files:
        for keyword in keywords:
            idx.setdefault(keyword, [])
            if keyword in files[file]:
                idx[keyword].append(keyword_in_file[file])
    return idx


def getid():
    idt= {}
    counter=0
    for file in files:
        idt[file]= counter+1
        counter += 1
    return idt


keywords=[]
for file in files:
    files [file]= lower(files[file])
    dictionary= tokenize(files[file])
    keywords= individualwords(dictionary)

keyword_in_file = getid()
final_dictionary= inverted_index()
#print(final_dictionary)
```

printing the whole thing works just fine - it shows me all words + the documents they are included in.

The second part, however, is where the issue seems to appear. I have to be able to serach for words by means of a query, e.g. 'fog' AND 'soup'. I also have to implement an OR option. The instructions for this part specifically said to use posting lists. This is my code so far:

```
def AND (l1, l2):
    result = []
    i1, i2 = 0,0
    while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
        doc1 = l1 [i1]
        doc2 = l2 [i2]
        if doc1 == doc2:
            yield doc1
            i1 += 1
            i2 += 1
        elif doc1 < doc2:
            i1+=1
        else: i2 += 1
    return result


def OR (list1, list2):
    result = list()
    len1 = len(list1)
    len2 = len(list2)
    if len1 >=len2:
        result = list1
        for search_word in list2:
            if search_word not in result:
                result.append(search_word)
    else:
        result = list2
        for search_word in list2:
            if search_word not in result:
                result.append(search_word)
    return result



query= str (input("Enter query: "))
while (query != "NULL"):
    data = query.split()
    op1 = list()
    op2 = list()
    temp = 0
    while temp < len(data):
        op2.append(data[temp])
        temp = temp+2
    temp = 1
    while temp < len(data):
        op1.append(data[temp])
        temp = temp+2

   #this is where an error occurs: "posting_lists.append(final_dictionary[search_word])", KeyError 
    posting_lists = list()
    for search_word in op2:
        posting_lists.append(final_dictionary[search_word])

    result = list()
    if len(op1) == 1:
        if op1[0] == "and":
            result = AND(posting_lists[0], posting_lists[1])

        elif op1[0] == "or":
            result = OR(posting_lists[0], posting_lists[1])

    else:
        for i in range(0, len(op1)):
            for i in range(0, len(op1)):
                if op1[i]=="and" or op1[i]=="&":
                    result= AND(posting_lists[0], posting_lists[1])
                elif op1[i]=="or" or op1[i]=="|":
                    result= OR(posting_lists[0], posting_lists[1])
```

Whenever I enter a search term, I keep getting a KeyError, saying that there is something wrong at `posting_lists.append(final_dictionary[search_word])`
and I have no idea what to do. I literally tried everything - I changed various things to be a list or a dictionary, etc. and nothing worked. I also read up on a lot of things but nothing seemed to help in this case.
I hope someone here can help me and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track by printing out `final_dictionary`.  You're getting the KeyError because the word you're looking for isn't in `final_dictionary`.  So then you would want to focus your debugging on `inverted_index()` to determine why the search word(s) you are expecting aren't being included in the dictionary.  I would print out each `keyword` to verify they are going to get added to `idx`.

I would also focus on this block of code:

```py
keywords=[]
for file in files:
    files [file]= lower(files[file])
    dictionary= tokenize(files[file])
    keywords= individualwords(dictionary)  ### <<<=== ????
```

I think you want to add the individual words to `keywords`; it seems you are reassigning `keywords` with every iteration of the `for` loop.